# WebScraping information by searching zipcodes

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, mechanicalsoup

I am trying to get information from this website https://caressearch.myflfamilies.com/PublicSearch
What I would like to get is **Provider Name, Address, Phone** but additionally I need to expand by clicking the name of the provider and get two more information **Capacity** and **Status**.

I tried to do that by webscraping tools succeed for the first part but could not succeed with the second part.

Another issue I have is, how can I add search input, like zipcodes in this instance. Is there a way to feed all zipcode inputs from one file so I do not need to manually input 1000 zipcodes to get all the childcare providers of Florida.

I thought about inputting zipcodes instead of getting the data in full, because website can only show 200 centres at once, and I could not see an option to show more centres. Although there are 943 centres in Miami for example, it only shows 200, then going by zipcodes can help a little bit
if we compartmentalize data.

I am a newbie and I would like to learn how I can achieve more knowledge on this topic. I reviewed similar questions but since the website cannot provide specific url for each centre, I could not find a way to retrieve the information.

Thanks for your help in advance.

I am a newbie and I would like to learn how I can achieve more knowledge on this topic. I reviewed similar questions but since the website cannot provide specific url for each centre, I could not find a way to retrieve the information.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.